# Short story about aliens that took the deer

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, dreams

I could be wrong, it was so long ago, but I thought the premise of it was that aliens had come to Earth and were communicating with people in their dreams, telling everyone they were judging to bring away the best that the Earth has to offer, and give them a paradise away from Earth.

So the main character and everyone were judged, all their thoughts and actions and everything, and then the main character woke up, knowing she was not pure enough for them, and she looked out the window and like none of humanity were pure or good enough.

So the aliens took the deer, the most pure and graceful of the world, and they left humanity to continue in a world of sin they had made for themselves.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Yeah, the deer were a very significant part of it, at least from what I remember.

Comment: It sounds like the aliens or the writer confused deer with dear.